# Houseplant with dark green and cream variegated leaves

Tags: identification, houseplants

[image]

Hello! Can anyone tell me what this is! And is it just thirsty or does it need support?

Answer (score 1):

This plant is a member of the [Hypoestes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypoestes_phyllostachya), probably Hypoestes phyllostachya.  There are so many cultivars it is hard to identify it precisely.

The plant is dry and should be watered immediately. It does best in filtered sun and has some small insignificant flowers.  The main attraction is the leaves.

This plant benefits from being cut back and the cuttings will root in water so you can keep it compact and make more at the same time.